# react-axios handle error don't get the message from the server

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios

I have a problem to get my custom error message from the server.

I'm using axios to make the call and Express as a server.

I got the status of the error but don't success to get the message only the status.

Express-Server response

```
 res.status(420).json({ message: "some problem" });
```

react axios call

```
    export function* deleteItem(action) {
  try {
    yield put(actions.deleteItemStart());
    yield axios.delete("/items/item/" + action.itemId);

   yield put(actions.deleteItemSuccess());
  } catch (error) { 
      console.log(error);
    yield put(actions.deleteItemFailed(error));
  }
}
```

this the error I get without the message

```
Error: Request failed with status code 420
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

this is my first post I hope it's all clear.

thanks in advance Gilad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can get axios errors with

```
catch(e){

  console.log("error response:", e.response);
}
```

e.response contains the server response if there is one.